# How to prevent grounding issue on Mini DisplayPort

Tags: circuit-design, grounding, monitor

I am attempting to design a board that has a Mini DisplayPort output.

When I plug a Mini DisplayPort cable into the board and measure the ground (system ground against Mini DisplayPort shield,) I get expected value of 0 ohms. When I use a monitor that uses a VGA to mini dp adapter, the value becomes around 50 ohms.

What is the proper way of designing an isolated Mini DisplayPort to avoid any grounding issues?

Comment: Please show your measurement setup.

Comment: How are you attempting to make the board? Is there schematics to comment on?

Comment: I suspect it is no coincidence that DisplayPort uses 50Ω termination resistors and you are measuring 50Ω somewhere. It's likely that you're measuring the wrong thing.